# Get a single random key from a php array while inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have a photo gallery that's generated using a simple PHP `foreach` loop and I would like to insert advertisements within the gallery as images.

The array for ads looks like this:

```
$links = array(
    'http://a.com' => 'a.jpg',
    'http://b.com' => 'b.jpg',
    'http://c.com' => 'c.jpg',
);
```

Now I need to take a **single pair** of `link + image` from this array while still inside the foreach loop after every x amount of iterations.

So I should probably be doing it in here:

```
if($count % 5 == 0){
 //get random item
} 
$count++;
```

Where `$count = 0;` stays outside the `foreach` loop.

I just haven't figured out a way to take **only one** of the items randomly from my array of links while inside the `foreach` loop.

Basically the end result should be something like:

```
<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>

<a href="link">
 <img src="picture"></img>
</a>

<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>
<img src="path"></img>

<a href="link">
 <img src="picture"></img>
</a>
```

etc.

Where the **link in the middle** of a set of `img's` is the one chosen randomly from my array and the set of `img's` are generated by my `foreach` loop like normal.

So far I've only been able to put my entire array as links after every 5 `img's` which is not what I need. The idea is to "spread out" through the photo gallery.

I'm not even sure any more if I have been working for too long or is it impossible... or am I approaching it wrong?

Note: I don't care if the ads repeat.

Comment: So you only want one but you don't care if they repeat? I'm not too sure on exactly the output you want. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the loop, shuffle the ads, making sure you don't destroy the keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($links);
shuffle($keys);
foreach($keys as $key) {
     $links_shuffled[$key] = $links[$key];
}
```

Then in the loop you have:

```
if($count % 5 == 0){
    //get random item
    $item = $links_shuffled[($count / 5) % count($links)];
    // output link:
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php) to select a random $link element every 5th iteration:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if($count % 5 == 0){
        $addUrl = array_rand($links);
        $addImage = $links[$addUrl]
    } 
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: This only gets the image and not the url?

Comment: true. I just edited my answer. array_rand returns a key, and the key is your url, right?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: After re-reading your question (again) it seems that the idea you have already should work. Can you show your full code rather than just little bits of it, so we can establish what is actually going wrong?

---

**NOTE: Everything below here was my original answer, which is probably not what the OP was actually asking.**

Not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, as the question wasn't completely clear. But I have a guess, you could do something like this...

```
$links = shuffle($links);
if($count % 5 == 0){
 //get random item
 $output = array_pop($links);
} 
$count++;
```

Essentially what this is doing, it will randomize the order of the array, then every 5 elements (or whatever value you put in the if statement), set $output to the value of the last element of the array, and remove the last element of the array so it cannot be used again. That way, when you next hit that if statement and it evaluates to true, you will take the last element of the array which cannot be a repeated value.

If I have misunderstood the object of what you are trying to achieve, then please explain clearer and I will happily adjust my answer accordingly.